# DOM Validation after a lot of JS dom injection/manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does anyone know of a tool to validate a page's DOM after manipulation and injection.

The problem is that I have a very complex page with some html injected via js from a CMS (which isn't always neat sadly) also a lot of dom elements being added and removed via the JS UI elements on the page plus a load of other MVC style parts. firebug etc tends to close tags themselves. I suppose I could log out the whole DOM tree and paste it into a validator but I'm looking for something a bit more elegant?

**EDIT:**

for clarification: I have a project where the DOM is being messed up, but there can be tens, perhaps up to 200 scraps of HTML complied using JS templates (mustache) in an MVC (backbone) pattern, as well as user and CMS input. I'm looking for a handy tool which can snapshot the DOM in any scenario and give me clearer pointers than built into Dev.Tools/ Firebug

Comment: Things like unclosed tags can't exist in the DOM.  An element either exists or doesn't.  I guess you could still have problems such as block elements where they are not valid, but unclosed tags won't be an issue with dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong here, but validation is for the HTML *document* being passed to the browser. Anything you do to the DOM after it's been parsed and loaded isn't really subject to validation rules. Plus, there's no guarantee that a dump of the DOM in one W3C-compliant browser is going to be identical to the same dump in another browser. That's why if you check the `innerHTML` on older versions of IE, you'd see non-validating data in there, like `<TD COLSPAN=3>`; that stuff is obviously non-valid in the W3C standard, but it's perfectly valid by definition to IE.

And, unfortunately, if you are injecting whole chunks of HTML into a browser via JS, that stuff will never validate because of all the stuff it's missing (like `<head>` and `<html>`).

One thing you can do (and I've looked at doing on our CMS, which has lots of user-generated HTML in it, which is often pretty broken) is load the text of the fragment into an XML shell like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container>{html_string_to_validate}</container>
```

And then load that into an XML parser (any type will do). This won't catch HTML issues, but it will catch nesting and entity issues. There may be some kinks you have to work out (I think it's possible for some parsers to kick up warnings if it sees empty tags like `<script src="..."></script>`).

Comment: Hey, yes, sorry I'm going to clarify my question, basically there are instances where the markup is broken either because of back-end input (sadly the cms allows palintext scraps of HTML), but there have been a few instances where my MVC views have had typos also. Basically the DOM at any point is made up of many views from JS mustache templates, populated by CMS driven content and the DOM tree is being broken in a few places and circumstances and I'm looking fo a handy tool to help.

Comment: It looks like Backbone has a `validate()` method, which probably would help with your templates. For your html fragments, I would consider putting a JS XML validator in to your CMS (they're easy to build, if not very cross-browser compatible) to tell the author that the code has problems. Also, I hate it when people tell me this, but if you're sending HTML fragments as data to an MVC application, you're kind of undoing the benefits of MVC. Consider ways to unbind the data from the markup and leave it to the controller to sort it out. MVC makes cross-platform possible; this makes it impossible.

Comment: yes, this is meant to be overwritten in order to validate data input but can be used to traverse the nodes of data i guess. Ive found a few killer bookmarklets which help a bit but not exactly what i want: http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/  https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/validation.html    http://slayeroffice.com/?c=/content/tools/suite.html

Comment: The spec says validation rules apply to dynamic DOM content.  E.g. "Conformance checkers ... should also check that the input document conforms when parsed with a browsing context in which scripts execute, and that the scripts never cause non-conforming states to occur other than transiently during script execution itself. (This is only a "SHOULD" and not a "MUST" requirement because it has been proven to be impossible. [COMPUTABLE])" - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#conformance-classes

Answer (score 0):

[Total Validator](https://www.totalvalidator.com) allows you to validate the DOM after javascript has run. You need to install the free application and then their browser extension. Then you just click on an icon on whatever page you want validating and it will send the DOM to the application to validate it.